# How can i add more than one List in a unique List and show it in a ListView - Xamrin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to put more than one List into a unique List, but i have a problem, to make a List you need to put a Model and one of each List that i have had his unique Model

```
        public Task<List<SQLite_ventas_factura>> GetVentasFacturaAsync()
        {
            return _database.Table<SQLite_ventas_factura>().ToListAsync();
        }

        public Task<List<SQLite_ventas_pedido>> GetVentasPedidoAsync()
        {
            return _database.Table<SQLite_ventas_pedido>().ToListAsync();
        }
```

I have 2 List with differents Model, my question here is. How can i put this List in one unique List to show it in a ListView

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/templates/data-templates/selector

Comment: In addition to using a `DataTemplateSelector` as described in Jason's link, you'll want to define either an `Interface` or a `base class` that both models implement. E.g. `public interface IVentas { ... };` Use interface: `public class SQLite_ventas_factura : IVentas`.  Same for `pedido`. Then you can make `List<IVentas>` that includes both types.